# For each loop is sometimes very slow with the same details

Tags: .net, localization

We have implemented localization and while I am trying to get the menu items and their labels from the tables, the system sometimes shows the result in 1 sec and sometimes it takes about 8 seconds to show the records. The code that I have written is:

```
CommonManager commonManager = new CommonManager();
List<BMS.BusinessEntities.Menu> lstMenu = commonManager.GetMenu(lstResource);

foreach (BMS.BusinessEntities.Menu mnu in lstMenu)
{
    mnu.Menu1 = DbRes.T(mnu.Menu1.TrimEnd('\r', '\n'), "Menu", manager.UserProfile.Language2.Culture);

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal && mnu.MenuURL != null)
        mnu.MenuURL = mnu.MenuURL.Replace(@"/Web", "");
}
```

While debugging the line that is taking time is :

```
mnu.Menu1 = DbRes.T(mnu.Menu1.TrimEnd('\r', '\n'), "Menu", manager.UserProfile.Language2.Culture);
```

However, the same statement with same parameters give fast as well as slow output. Any thoughts??

Comment: How can we give a reasonable answer with the information you provided :) Share `DbRes.T` and `GetMenu` methods. And what db, ORM do you use?

Comment: The only thing that catches my eye is that you call `DbRes.T` in a foreach. Does that `DbRes.T` make some db calls? If so, include all that information in a single db call in `GetMenu`